# How does it follow that $me=em,$ as we no longer have the fact that $(M,p)$ has a unit?

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

I do not have enough reputation to comment, so I had to a make a post to ask this question. If this does not site standards feel free to remove it.

[What condition on $m$ turns this semigroup into a monoid?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147237/what-condition-on-m-turns-this-semigroup-into-a-monoid)

So in the above post user23211 (at the very bottom of the page) mentions that if $(M, p)$ is not a monoid then $(M, p_m)$ is also not a monoid. However, I don't seem to understand the reasoning there. Clearly $em$ is a left identity and $me$ is a right identity.

However, how does it follow that $me = em$ as we no longer have the fact that $(M,p)$ has a unit?

Comment: $me = p(em,me) = em$, using that $em$ is a left identity and $me$ a right identity. Thus $(M,p)$ would have a two-sided identity.

Comment: So if you had a two sided identity it follows that they are equal?

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for answering the question. If $lm = 1$ and $mr = 1$, then $lmr = r$ which implies $l = r$, $mr =1$.

Comment: Actually, $(M,p)$ might fail to be a monoid by not even being a semigroup. However, it seems we (implicitly) assume that $(xm)y=x(my)$ for all $x,y$. I do not yet see how we $(xy)z=x(yz)$ should follow for all $x,y,z\in M$ from only $(xmy)mz=xm(ymz)$

Comment: I believe that we are implicitly implying that $(M,p)$ is a semigroup and that $(M, p_m)$ is monoid which implies that $(xm)y = x(my)$. Otherwise I think your point is completely valid.